# MySQL and Advanced Where Clauses

Tags: mysql, dynamic, where-clause

I am doing some work with mysql and have a unique situation where the only solution that comes to me is to have every possible combination defined. I am wondering if there is an easier/better way of doing this.

This sql creates 5 categories of mpgs

```
SELECT
count(if(a.mpgcombined < 18, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under18,
count(if(a.mpgcombined >= 18 AND a.mpgcombined <= 23, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under24,
count(if(a.mpgcombined > 23 AND a.mpgcombined <= 28, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under29,
count(if(a.mpgcombined > 28 AND a.mpgcombined <= 35, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as under36,
count(if(a.mpgcombined > 35, a.mpgcombined, NULL)) as over35
FROM styles a, jpgs b, models c, divisions d
WHERE d.divisionid = c.divisionid
AND a.styleid = b.styleid
AND c.modelid = a.modelid
AND a.mktclassid in ($this->mktclassids)
$this->where
AND a.sequence = 0;
```

These categories and there counts are then shown to the user as a bunch of checkboxes, but only if the count is greater than 0.

The user can then select as many category ranges as they want.

The problem I came across is that if a user selects under18 and under24, a where clause like this will not work:

```
AND a.mpgcombined < 18 AND a.mpgcombined >= 18 AND a.mpgcombined <= 23
```

This will obviously work:

```
AND a.mpgcombined <= 23
```

This stuff is dynamic so I do not know what the where conditions will be, so something like the first option allows me to not have to define sql for each possible scenario.

Is there anyway around not having to define the sql for every possible combination?
sql is not my strong point.

If you're thinking that this query will make no sense with that where clause, do not worry this sql does not get called if the user selects mpg, it gets disabled, but the where clause gets applied to several other querys.

How would I go about generating sql if say under18, under36, and over35 was chosen??
The user can choose any combination they want.

This is what I have in mind...basically 49 or whatever if and elseif statements for each possible scenario.

```
if(under18 && under24)
    $where = 'AND a.mpgcombined <= 23';
elseif (under29 && under18....)
```

You can get the picture of what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the MPG classes are mutually exclusive, the only way to combine them in a query is via an `OR` clause (since cars can only be in one *or* another).

So, you need to use something like

```
(a.mpgcombined < 18) OR (a.mpgcombined >= 18 AND a.mpgcombined <= 23)
```

i.e. put your class defining sub-clauses in parentheses and then combine them with an `OR` operator

You may need to put the whole resultant sub-clause in parentheses as well, if you're combining it with others, so that the `OR` clauses don't alter the meaning of your whole `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ok...so if this is only apart of a large where clause i could do something like this     AND ((a.mpgcombined < 18) OR (a.mpgcombined >= 18 AND a.mpgcombined <= 23))

Comment: @user2506624, I agree with this approach... what happens if someone does something like anyone over 35, but also wants under 24 (which is actually 18-23).  You need to get both demographics on their own merits and the "OR" should be the right solution